# Looking for particular alert box behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm interested in alert boxes such as,

http://www.visual-blast.com/javascript/nice-alert-box-with-jquery-impromptu/

and

http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/08/design-stunning-alert-box-using.html

but with a different functionality, the user should be able to interact with the page even with the alert box present, so it needs to be movable and not obscure the underlying page, as in this example,

http://www.open-lab.com/mb.ideas/index.html

Alert box should be generated automatically on page view plus the title and message of the alert box should change with each page refresh from expandable library.

Is there anything out there like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the jQuery UI dialog widget might do what you need?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](http://www.chrisesler.com/mootools/mootools-dragwindow.html) with mootools. You easily can extend any element on the page to be draggable. You may use [this plugin](http://www.coders.me/ejemplos/sexy-alert-box-1-2/) as a sample of alerts and you'll just need to remove some functionality and add make it draggable.

Answer (score 0):

There are few custom dialogs in moo.rd. One of them is the Custom.Alert:
http://www.moord.it/examples/custom_alert